# Convert English text to Hindi which is coming from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, html

I have data stored in mysql DB in English language. I want to show that data in Hindi to the user on front-end which is written in HTML5 and angularjs.
Currently I am storing English as well as Hindi translation of that data in DB and if user wants to see it in Hindi then i  am fetching Hindi Content from Database and displaying on front-end which is working so very fine but ...Is there any other and easy way to that?

Because I always have to translate the English data in Hindi and store it in DB, real problem is data is changing every week so I have to do that every week.

Comment: Please help me in understanding the situation. Are you trying to solve the problem wherein you have to update Hindi to English mapping? Or are you looking for an elegant way to handle translation? For the latter, you might want to look at ng-translate as pointed out in the answer. I am not sure if you can get away with updation of Hindi to English mapping, given data changes every week.

Comment: My query is if data is stored in database in English language then how to show that same data in Hindi on front-end. Like, is there any way angular can do translation once it get the data from DB or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [ng-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide). I don't know how reliable it is for hindi though.